# Possible revenge downvoting, not caught by the serial downvoting detector

Tags: discussion, serial-voting, behavior

There was a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32033175/c-memory-allocation-for-struct-with-malloc) that I answered in SO. The OP had asked a series of questions about his code, and I answered one of them. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32033175/c-memory-allocation-for-struct-with-malloc/32033206#32033206) gives the concept that is responsible for the behavior of the OP's code and then gives a link to the full description of the concept. The answer wasn't great, but it got upvoted.

Some guy had a better answer than me, it answered most of the OP's questions, I also upvoted that answer. In the beginning my answer somehow had more upvotes, so 2 users ambushed me that time. I explained that it's not my fault that it got upvoted. They downvoted the answer and left rude comments. Now, they are on a spree downvoting my old answers and questions.

It was pointed out that there exists scripts that detect this kind of behaviour. But, the question is more than 3 days old, and this was not detected or reverted back. So to bring it to the attention, I posted this.

What should I do?

Comment: Voting is anonymous, so you don't know if they are the ones behind it. But serial downvoting is not allowed on SO, and we have scripts to detect and reverse it.

Comment: @S.L.Barth, Voting is anonymous, but when a series of questions and answers older then 8-9 months as well as newer ones gets downvoted suddenly in one day, then there is a very clear indication. And, the scripts did not detect it, and they are still the way it was after getting downvoted.

Comment: Downvoting is anonymous, unless you were standing over their shoulders and watching their voting, then all you have are assumptions - far away from facts.

Comment: The scripts run 1/day, I believe. How long ago was it?

Comment: @santiago there is something called logic. When questions and answer lay untouched for months, and suddenly after this questions, some gets downvoted in a day, then i don't know how its an assumption.

Comment: Still not necessarily facts, follow @S.L.Barth's advice below

Comment: I hope this new title will keep the question from being closed.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Ya, Thanx

Comment: The resentment expressed in the comments on your post do highlight a very real problem.  There is entirely too much hanky-panky going on these days.  SO users just don't trust voting anymore, your post fits the profile.  We are not allowed to talk about it and any suggestion of fraud is always shouted-down with "you can't be sure".  That an SO user applies vigilante justice to try to correct the situation by himself is a fairly inevitable outcome.  It really *needs* to be corrected, voting is absolutely crucial.  Well, the machine will likely take care of it.

Comment: And no, there is no evidence of hanky-panky in your profile.  But this evolving lack of trust in voting does create an atmosphere were users are assumed guilty until proven innocent.  Not good.  This is going to blow up sooner or later, hopefully soon.

Comment: @HansPassant Just before sometime, 2 of those answers got reverted and i got back the points.

Comment: @HansPassant and there is a growing amount of hostility to people who offer the alternative view, that maybe, just maybe it is a coincidence - assumptions are not facts.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that the comments on the post are not a coincidence.  And of course they were their assumptions, not mine.  Don't shoot the messenger please.

Comment: I'll often comment about something, and then a down vote will pop up that wasn't mine. There isn't necessarily a correlation between the two, even if there looks like there is - there's a lot of 'eyeballs' on recent posts. Trundling through past questions for someone... well, almost inevitably will attract some votes one way or another (especially if it's ordered by 'best answers').

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_clumping is always an option...

Comment: @Sobrique: I like to make constructive comments pointing out flaws in an answer and give the poster time to respond before I downvote. But it's not unusual for me to post such a comment and then soon after the answer is downvoted (and perhaps my comment is upvoted). Presumably some of the people who downvoted wouldn't have noticed the problem with the answer if not for my comment. In that situation I can understand the OP suspecting me of downvoting them, or even being part of a gang of downvoters.

Comment: (cont) And even if they fix their answer & I upvote them, they can't tell whether it's a fresh upvote or merely a reversion of a previous downvote. I guess that can't be helped.

Comment: I have just found `StackEye` which looks like it'll do what I want - I can comment and 'watch' with a view to amending my vote (and deleting comment) later. Otherwise I often just vote based on how it looks _right now_ because I may not look back later.

Comment: If you think your case deserves individual human attention, you can email the moderators. But I warn you: they are very resistant to this sort of thing. I once got 4 downvotes on 4 different questions within 5 minutes of each other, after months of no downvotes anywhere, just after a bitter wrangle with another user. I alerted the moderators, and they said it was just coincidence and there was no hanky-panky going on. I still don't believe that, but it is certainly true that as long as your answers are sitting out there in public, _some_ of them _will_ downvoted occasionally.

Comment: Why is it so important to some that you add / lose some points?  You should be confident that overtime your knowledge will prevail if you are certain you have a good answer.  I hate questions like this because it shows too much of an attachment to points.

Comment: How many of these mysterious down-votes are you getting? If there are 2 people who are going around down-voting everything you post, okay, you get an automatic -2 on every post. That would be hard to distinguish from "real" down-votes. I don't keep track but I think most of my posts get no down-votes, but 1 or 2 isn't unusual. If there's really some mob of dozens of people out to "punish" you, or if it's one or two people who have created dozens of accounts, then the story is different.

Comment: One thing I don't understand: now that it has been pointed out to you that your answer is wrong (it does not answer the OP's question at all), why don't you remove it?

Comment: @Hans Passant If a large number of someone's older questions all receive downvotes around the same time, then all "no evidence of hanky-panky in your profile" means is that the downvoting ring is sophisticated enough to fool you. There's no legitimate pattern that can produce that outcome.

Answer (score 51):

This being a crowd-sourced internet device, you will get:

- upvotes you can't explain
- downvotes you don't deserve
- unfriendly comments
- strange comments
- and grand pianos flying out of black holes

There is no way on earth that any number of maids with any number of mops could sweep up all occurrences. The mods and team strive to fix the *serious* misbehaviors -- the unreasonably nasty comments, the nontrivial serial votes. For the rest, the only cure is to have a thick skin. In the gray ooze in between one tactical vote and 23 in two minutes, there's plenty of room for unpleasantness, and I suppose this is what's on Hans' radar screen. However, if you plug along creating good content, your normal, neutral-to-positive interaction may still overwhelm the goo. This can 'discourage the newcomer' to *any* arena with a very large population of evaluators. The alternative, which I suppose is to very tightly limit the right to evaluate, has scaling problems. If you don't / can't have a thick skin, you might be discouraged and wander off. Well, hmm, is this a tragedy? Only, at this point, if you are a unique expert on some subject and questions will go languishing. No offense, but that's pretty rare.

Look, here I am with 57K votes, and I've decided that *my* skin isn't thick enough for the review queues, so I've bid them goodbye. I don't bother to call them out as broken any more, I've just decided to leave them to better pachyderms than me.

Comment: Hey, I want a piano too!

Comment: @Bergi, I believe that your comment was upvoted just to prove bmargulies' arguments.

Comment: _"If you don't like it go away"_ is a terrible argument. Being treated unfairly cannot be shrugged off forever. Just as you turned your back to review queues, most users turned their back to asking and answering questions due to perceived moderator Nazis. Instead of telling people to stop whining solve the problem.

Comment: Most users? Got a stat to go with that ridiculous claim? Godwin's law arrives. Goodbye.

Answer (score 36):

Judging by the comments, some people believed that you got the quick upvotes in an unfair way - that you had a voting ring.

And then some users - the same ones or others - decided to go on a bit of vigilante justice.
In doing so, they did two things wrong:

1. If you suspect that someone is using sock puppets or a voting ring, you should *flag* them. Then the SE team can see if something fishy is going on, or if it is a false alarm.
2. Serial voting is not allowed on Stack Exchange. Neither serial upvoting nor serial downvoting. We have scripts that run daily to detect this and revert it. If people are indeed serial downvoting you, they can expect some attention from the moderators.

Now the question is, assuming this was indeed a deliberate act of serial downvoting, why didn't the scripts catch it?
The formulae used by the scripts are kept secret. This is deliberate; otherwise it would be too easy to dodge them. But it is still possible that some people found a way to "fly under the radar".

So, you did right to bring this up on Meta. You may want to keep track of the exact numbers (how many downvotes / day). If you believe there is enough evidence that revenge downvoting is going on, you may want to flag your own post for moderator attention, and provide them with the numbers.

One thing to keep in mind before using a moderator flag: you are not objective. If you have friends who are also SO users, you may want to discuss it with one of them first, in person. Try to make your report as objective as you can.

Comment: I know i am clean from any voting ring. And about being detected by the moderators for serial voting, i waited 2-3 days, but nothing happened. So only i posted it here.

Comment: Not to be rude or anything, But what everyone is stressing at, "scripts, sounds like the following situation. A person witnesses a murder, goes to report it to the police, and the police says that there are laws and policemen to check that murder doesn't happen and if it happens also, the murderer will be caught and punished. So please don't disturb else i will downvote your this question also.

Comment: The loss of 2 fake internet points does not even remotely relate to murder - that is a non-comparison

Comment: @santiago thats a reference to the situation, not a comparison. One is not suppose to compare the seriousness of the situations, but the way things are happening. and btw, i just got another downvote on my old question. I dunno if this post helped me or is having the revrese effect.

Comment: No need to be patronising, the loss of points and the *procedures to deal with it* are not as serious, not even remotely, as real life crimes in any way.

Comment: @santiago It is serious for a new comer who will get discouraged with this kind of behavior. Anyways, i flagged the answer and i think it helped. 2 downvotes for my answer got reverted back. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @harris You're seeing the meta effect on your answer. Brining attention to them via a meta post can have positive but most often have negative effects, specially if it is about a few down votes.

Comment: @haris If someone goes to the police, and reports that someone dropped a pen cap on the street -- blatant littering!  You grabbed the pen cap with your tweezers, put it in a bag.  You want the police to dust it for prints, and go arrest the person who you saw drop the pen cap (he's a greying red head who drives a yellow vespa, 2013 model, with a W-shaped scratch on the size, and the license plate starts with a Q and has two 7s in it) and compare the print to the pen cap, do you expect the police to run out and start investigating?  That is why people are talking about scripts.

Answer (score 18):

As others have indicated, if you feel that you have been the target of serial downvoting, cast a flag on one of your posts and explain what you think is happening. The serial voting script is conservative, and certain users have probed its limits as they attempt to abuse the voting system.

Two such users clearly targeted you here. One of them has a history of this, and he has been suspended for a significant duration. If he is found to do this again, he will no longer be welcome to participate on this site. This message has been made abundantly clear to him.

Some of these targeted votes were invalidated by the system, and an SE employee has been notified to clean up the rest.

I highly recommend not engaging with anyone you suspect of doing this. First, many people make bad assumptions about who is attacking them with downvotes and lash out at the wrong person. Second, retaliating against someone with harsh comments or downvotes can turn a dispute into a feud, and I really hate having to clean those up.

Again, if the serial downvoting you experience is not caught by the script, and is a strong enough pattern to indicate that you're being targeted by someone, just flag it and let us handle the rest. A downvote here or there is probably not something worth acting on, but consistent, large-scale patterns could point to a problem, as they did here.

Comment: Thanx a lot for the advice. :) 

I will follow it next time and avoid such confrontations.