# 'Serial Downvotes Theory' and countermeasures

Tags: discussion, downvotes, serial-voting

I was serially downvoted on many of my question twice this month. The questions are legitimate and the downvotes are completely unnecessary.

The script to identify the fraud didn't work to reverse the latest series of downvotes (on Dec 18) as the downvotes were cleverly done by multiple users, probably 2 or 3 at a time. I could think of the following cases that could've happened:

1. Multiple users (accomplices) were involved.
2. A single user with multiple accounts was involved.
3. To bypass the time constraint they downvoted 2 to 3 questions at a time. Making a total 10 questions in a day.

**Here are a few that were not reversed properly by script:**

[image]

**Here are a few that were reversed properly by script:**

[image]

Can the script to detect such downvote frauds be enhanced to check the number of downvotes a **single user** gets in a day for **old (having a clean record)** questions?

I concur with Stack Overflow's culture to have anonymous downvoting. Ideas and efforts [don't need a profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3741717/identity1?tab=profile).

But this is something equivalent to spamming/fraud. I **don't** ask for a rule to make it mandatory for users to comment. These fraud voter will always find a comment. I ask for an enhancement in identification script. It can use some factors like the following in a [chain like fashion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern):

1. [Chronology factor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303130/possible-revenge-downvoting-not-caught-by-the-serial-downvoting-detector?rq=1#comment237095_303130): New and old question downvoted at the same time for a single user. (See Haris's comments )
2. Frequency factor: Downvotes frequently happening from a user to a user.
3. Temporal factor: Downvotes happening from a user on multiple questions in a very short period of time.
4. Crowd-Source (Optionally): Add a review queue to identify legitimacy of suspicious downvotes

Comment: What Bart says - an old question can pop up to the top for some reason, and then garner a lot of negative attention for entirely legitimate reasons. For your specific case, talk to the moderators

Comment: I've raised a moderator's attention flag already! Twice this month

Comment: @Identity1 I hope you don't mind, but for these questions, I would have downvoted as well. You are a pretty seasoned user to know that these questions aren't in the very best format. :)

Comment: If nothing happened due to those flags, either it's simply not visible to you, or there was nothing they (or employees) felt comfortable taking action on.

Comment: @ShamasS I agree that you may find my questions not worthy of an upvote. But what about my answers? I think some of them were downvoted completely unneccessarily

Comment: @Pekka웃 Thats flawed. Why would my 10 questions/answers suddenly pop together to be garnered with negativity?

Comment: We can debate that at length, but we have no insight into the situation. Just flag, and let those can handle it.

Comment: @Identity1 a *single* question, or a couple, could pop up, and gather a lot of negative votes. Not 10 though, agreed.

Comment: Let's not mince words, this is targeted voting.  Voting on a user instead of posts is pretty vile.  And yes, plenty of SO users keep more than one account.  I hate to say it and it most definitely should never be necessary but you might consider obfuscating your place of residence and alter your avatar.  Finding the voter back is pretty hard work for the moderators, they have to ask SE staff for help, they'll *eventually* get to it when the voting keeps repeating.  You can bypass by clicking the "Contact us" link at the bottom of the page.  Don't expect miracles.

Comment: I'll be dissappointed if the question is closed stating its a possible duplicate   of "Require a comment explaining the reason" question. Please choose something else to close this question not this. Its not relevant.

Comment: I didn't even know there was a script to detect suspicious voting.  It doesn't seem to work for me, because I had a question down voted 6 times in less than a minute after I asked it, and I find it a little hard to believe that was legit.  And of course, for a third time in a row on SE, I am now banned from asking questions.

Comment: @cluemein i doubt your case is relevant to this question in any way shape or form. It's more likely people downvoted due to the reason outlined in your comment to one of the answers: "My problem was mainly missing parameters and typos"

Comment: Relevant if you know who the offender is (you ticked them off so you should have some idea): [The "Bigger Person" Technique: Upvote, and leave a constructive comment on one or more of the offender's posts.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312496/4639281)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

A few points of clarification here: the 10 downvotes that you received originally were from one person and all were invalidated by the script. I warned that person yesterday about this, in response to your flags. I missed the additional four votes, but I have reason to believe they came from the same person. From examining the evidence I have, I do not believe multiple accounts were involved.

The serial voting script is designed to be conservative, in order to prevent false positives. Even so, sometimes legitimate voting is invalidated by the script. Moderators regularly provide feedback to SE about cases that we think the script should have caught, and I know they are working on better tooling around the detection and invalidation of these votes.

Even moderators aren't privy to the inner workings of the serial voting script, but we've seen a lot of cases like this so we can make some guesses as to how it operates. SE staff have also provided hints publicly about this. Points 1 through 3 on your list are already taken into account in a weighted fashion, from what I can tell.

Point 4 would be a terrible idea, as it would expose voting information to average users without the proper context to judge it. Even moderators cannot see specific votes, and we have signed a privacy agreement in order to get access to even see trends. We look into user histories to determine if these votes were triggered by an argument or were legitimate attempts to vote on quality of content. I don't see how community review could pick out anything we couldn't, and such a system would lead to feuds and witch hunts.

Comment: I have to tell you, a legitimate reason for "serial downvoting" is this.  Sometimes I see a particularly bad question or answer, so I look at the users question/answer history, and when I do so I find a large number of other bad ones, so downvoting multiple times in a row on a single user need not be about the user, just that this was how I came upon them.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch The general rule of thumb is not to go through a user's profile and look at all their posts and downvote a bunch of them. While you may be voting on _quality_ rather than _user,_ by searching specifically through their profile to find those posts and downvote them, you _are_ still technically targetting the user, since it's only _their_ posts you're looking at.

Comment: @Kendra - No, it's not.  I'm not "technically" voting on quality, I *am* voting on quality, and it's no different than if those posts appeared on the front page (let's say someone retagged a bunch of them and they all showed up on the front page at once).  The questions/answers are all public, and regardless of how I come upon them, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I didn't say you were "technically" voting on quality. I assumed, and said, that you were voting on quality rather than the user, but if you're looking _at their profile_ then you have zero chance of seeing posts by others when you click on the link of a post unless you bother to read other posts attached to that one. What I'm saying is, while you're heart is in the right place (You are _not_ trying to vote on the person, your goal is quality.) You are _still_ targeting the user. On the front page, even after some strange mass-retag, you'll still _see other posts._

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch that wasn't the case here for sure as some of my answers having a 3+ Score were also downvoted. Also, I'm sure it takes at least a minute to completely read the questions and comments. Not 4 questions in a minute

Comment: @Identity1 - I wasn't suggesting that was the case here, more that any script that detected what you want would consider real use cases as false positives.

Comment: @BradLarson.. Thanks! And the reversal was done today!

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch "of course it's easy to find... user profiles - full of terrible stuff. But if you're going to review them, do it right: up-vote the good stuff, down-vote the bad stuff, edit the stuff that should be edited, leave comments where you can do some good that way... If you can't do that, then you're not really giving these posts a fair shake and you shouldn't be reviewing them at all..." ([How should I balance serial downvoting with the discovery that a poster has a lot of downvotable posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210257/165773))

Answer (score 15):

I am not a fan of this.  Imagine you have users A, B and C that are regulars in tag X.  Now user N decides the are going to start learning X and the ask a very basic easily google-able question about tag X. Now users A, B and C see the question and down vote and vote to close as it adds nothing to Stack Overflow.  A little later on user X asks another question that is very unclear and lacks an MCVE.  The same three users are on again and they do the same thing.

Now in the above scenario with your proposed changes those rightful down votes by users that are moderating and policing their tag would get reversed as they all "targeted" the user and all voted about the same time.

I do not think we need to add anything more to what is already caught as I would rather have to report a case of serial voting that did not get corrected than have non serial voting get "corrected".  If serial voting does not get corrected automatically then you can also use the [**contact us**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) link or use a custom flag and let the mods handle it.

Comment: I intend to suggest an improvement on the existing script. The script will only identify suspicious downvotes. Reviewers will do the rest.