# Accepted answer with four downvotes

Tags: discussion, downvotes, specific-answer

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35914075/5678086) is a simple answer I posted on how to execute a Java program. It got accepted by the poster also. But why are there are four downvotes?

Downvoters didn't put any comments either. I have been on Stack Overflow for the past two months only. This is the first time I am getting this kind of experience. I don't really understand why this happened.

Comment: As a warning this post will most likely attract more downvotes to your answer.

Comment: You may want to do some further reading into revenge downvoting to get an idea of why people choose not to comment and why voting is anonymous: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303130/possible-revenge-downvoting-not-caught-by-the-serial-downvoting-detector

Comment: Thank you for the alert @JoeW and Gimby

Comment: I don't know why this question in meta is also getting down-votes. Even it has got a good answer from @CodeCaster, which may be useful for many new user like me.

Comment: Downvoting in meta is different and isn't actually any kind of negative thing - nor does it impact your account. People downvote for different reasons here but it generally boils down to "don't agree", "don't want", etc. Its information you can use or ignore, not judgement.

Comment: @Thanga the question has answers which are specific to this question, removing the question makes it hard to see how the answers are relevant to that question which is unfair on the answerers. That's why I've rolled it back.

Comment: @RobertLongson I understand. I have modified my answer as per the suggestions in the answers here. Thank you

Comment: Now you can remove the "downvoters plz leave comment" comment. Don't bother leaving those in the future, no one reads them. The people who downvoted your answer don't wait around to see if you'll post a comment.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I guess it is because you're not properly addressing the problem at hand, you're merely providing a workaround.

A *proper* answer would be something like this:

> You're getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because you're accessing the command line arguments without checking that there actually are any.
>
> You need to check whether the user provided the proper arguments, and if not, print a message how to call the executable.
>
> ```
> [code showing how to do so]
> ```
>
> When debugging, you can pass command line arguments to your application like this:
>
> [your current answer]

Also, you're answering a question that has about five thousand duplicates, which usually isn't really appreciated of users with more than 2K reputation. At least not by me.

In addition to that, as pointed out in comments here: you're abusing `inline code` to highlight random terms, which also isn't appreciated (see [When should code formatting be used for non-code text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text)).

Comment: Not to mention `abuse` of inline `code formatting` for things like `JAVA`. `Unbelievable`.

Comment: It's *not even* a workaround. The OP has passed arguments on the command line and gets the same exception because they're passing an out-of-range value as an argument (as the other answer correctly point out). Pointing to that settings dialog fixes absolutely nothing.

Comment: @Andrew I missed that, I just skimmed the answer. You're absolutely right. Feel free to post an own answer or edit that into mine.

Comment: Thanks CodeCaster and @AndrewMedico. I modified my answer as you guys suggested. Thanks for your time..

Comment: FYI, question is now closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

Your answer does not address the issues in the OP's code, which are that they're not checking the length of `args`, and their index argument (`5`) is out of range for their string of length 4 (`1234`). Pointing to that settings dialog does not fix either of those issues.

The OP indicates that they know how to pass arguments on the command line in the shell. Showing them how to do that in the IDE may save them a little time, but it doesn't fix their code.

Comment: That being said, the problem statement in the question _is_ caused by not passing arguments to the program, as the exception occurs on line 3, or `Integer.parseInt(args[1])`. The code simply has multiple problems.

Comment: I modified my answer as you you suggested. Thanks for your time..